# How can I get a vertical scrollbar in my ListBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, scrollviewer

In the example below I have a ListBox with dozens of font names in it.

I would have thought it would automatically have a vertical scrollbar on it so that you can select ANY font, not just the first ones in the list, but it doesn't.

So I added a "ScrollViewer" and that puts a "scrollbar area" on the right but there is no scrollbar in the scrollbar area so that you can scroll (!).

Why isn't a scrollbar automatic and how do I force it to have a scrollbar?

```
<StackPanel Name="stack1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Name="lstFonts" Margin="3"  ItemsSource="{x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The problem with your solution is you're putting a scrollbar around a ListBox where you probably want to put it inside the ListBox.

If you want to force a scrollbar in your ListBox, use the ScrollBar.VerticalScrollBarVisibility attached property.

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
</ListBox>
```

Setting this value to Auto will popup the scrollbar on an as needed basis.

Comment: In my case I had put the `ListBox` inside a `ScrollViewer` too and the `ListBoxItems` were stretching as wide as they wanted outside the size of the `ListBox`. Removing the `ScrollViewer` and setting `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` and `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` did the trick.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 40):

`ListBox` already contains `ScrollViewer`. By default the `ScrollBar` will show up when there is more content than space. But some containers resize themselves to accommodate their contents (e.g. `StackPanel`), so there is never "more content than space". In such cases, the `ListBox` is always given as much space as is needed for the content.

In order to calculate the condition of having more content than space, the size should be known. Make sure your `ListBox` has a constrained size, either by setting the size explicitly on the `ListBox` element itself, or from the host panel.

In case the host panel is vertical `StackPanel` and you want `VerticalScrollBar` you must set the Height on `ListBox` itself. For other types of containers, e.g. `Grid`, the `ListBox` can be constrained by the container. For example, you can change your original code to look like this:

```
<Grid Name="grid1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Name="lstFonts" Margin="3"
                 ItemsSource="{x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Note that it is not just the immediate container that is important. In your example, the immediate container is a `Grid`, but because that `Grid` is contained by a `StackPanel`, the outer `StackPanel` is expanded to accommodate its immediate child `Grid`, such that that child can expand to accommodate *its* child (the `ListBox`).

If you constrain the height at any point — by setting the height of the `ListBox`, by setting the height of the inner `Grid`, or simply by making the outer container a `Grid` — then a vertical scroll bar will appear automatically any time there are too many list items to fit in the control.

Comment: Using a DockPanel as parent container omits the need of knowing how many elements you plan to add as child or predefine any Height Attribute. For each child define DockPanel.Dock=Top. This make your "Scrollviewer-Childs" showing their Scrollbars as needed. Not tested generally, it did work in my usecase. BR, Daniel

Comment: TLDR: Change your parent element from `StackPanel` to `Grid` since StackPanel always expands to the height of its children.

Answer (score 18):

I added a "Height" to my ListBox and it added the scrollbar nicely.

Comment: Try to avoid using the height and width properties as they can make changes down the road difficult. You're better off going with JaredPar's solution.

Comment: I do that but it just puts a "scrollbar area" to the right with no scrollbar itself, and my list goes down past the bottom of my window down to all eternity, how can I tell the listbox (stop at the bottom of the window)?

Comment: Because it's in a StackPanel, it's merrily being given all the space it needs, so it doesn't think it *needs* a scrollbar.

Comment: This worked for me ( I've just set MinHeight and MaxHeight instead of fixed Height). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Scroll Bar is added to the List box automatically unless its visibility is set to Hidden. Whenever the size of List Items exceeds the one, which can be shown inside a list box vertical or horizontal list box can be seen during the run time.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the number of items in the ListBox is dynamic so I didn't want to use the Height property. I used MaxHeight instead and it works nicely. The scrollbar appears when it fills the space I've allocated for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, I had a ComboBox followed by a ListBox in a StackPanel and the scroll bar for the ListBox was not showing up. I solved this by putting the two in a DockPanel instead. I set the ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" and let the ListBox fill the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

**XAML ListBox Scroller - Windows 10(UWP)**

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
</Style>
```