# Xaml Listbox stretching the whole usercontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml

So I'm having a listbox showing some data in a usercontrol :

```
<UserControl x:Class="FSBEM.UCs.SomeUC"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

     <Grid Margin="7,0,9,0">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox"
                 SelectedValuePath="Id"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                 Margin="0,5,5,5">
                 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <DockPanel>
                              <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                                 <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}  {0} ">
                                        <Binding Path="Name" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                 </TextBlock.Text>
                              </TextBlock>
                              <Button x:Name="Btn_Delete"
                                      Padding="5,0,5,0"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                 <Image Source="/Media/Icons/Delete_Icon.png"
                                        Width="10"
                                        Height="10"/>
                              </Button>
                            </DockPanel>
                       </DataTemplate>
                  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <TextBox Name="txtBox"
                 Height="22"
                 Margin="0,14,5,5"/>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

and the problem is that the listbox does not stick to the main window border .. instead it stretches the whole usercontrol down beyond the main window .. I tried setting a MaxHeight but it's not a solution to me. I want to handle it to stick to the main window border and show a scrollbar when there is too mush data to display.

**UPDATE**
this is the xaml code for the MainWindow :

```
<Window x:Class="FSBEM.MainWindow"
        Height="471.997"
        Width="1186.374" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        WindowState="Maximized">

<ScrollViewer FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   <Grid x:Name="MainGrid"
         FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
        <Menu x:Name="menu"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Height="23"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" />

        <Grid Name="InnerGrid"
              Margin="0,23,0,20" />

   </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

and I'm showing the usercontrol in the "InnerGrid"

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the ListBox in a scrollviewer?

Comment: Yes I did. and it behaves the same

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472796/how-can-i-get-a-vertical-scrollbar-in-my-listbox

Comment: Can you show the main xaml where you insert the usercontrol? The problem may as well be there...

Comment: @rauland actually the problem is that the listbox is streching and viewing a scrollbar instead of sticking to the main window border

Comment: It really doesn't make any sense, since the `Grid` `RowDefinition.Height` is set to `40` in your example, so the whole list should be pretty much hidden and shrinked to nothing

Comment: @grek40 your comment made me realize the problem. I'll post the Solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem , it was the ScrollBarViewer in the MainWindow. that's why the listbox had the freedom to stretch. Removing the ScrollBarViewer solved the problem.